# php timezone: DateTime::createFromFormat ignores timezone

Tags: php, datetime

I'm using php 5.6.17 on debian 8. After set up owncloud, I noticed, that the 
logs which are self written by owncloud (not by apache) has wrong time zones.

I investigated this a bit, seems like, that the line:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("U.u", number_format(microtime(true), 4, ".", ""), 'Europe/Berlin');
```

This does not care about any timezone setting. Instead of the time for Europe/Berlin (+1/+2) I get always the time for UTC.

In `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` I set `"date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"` and the system time (debian) is also correct.

Even If I run somthing like below I get the same output (UTC):

```
 $time=DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', sprintf('%.6F', microtime(true)), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
 echo $time->format('c') . "\n";
 $time=DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', sprintf('%.6F', microtime(true)), new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
 echo $time->format('c') . "\n";
```

Any ideas about this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Quoting the [PHP manual on DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

> **Note:**
>   The timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the time parameter either contains a UNIX timestamp (e.g. 946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

If you want to change the timezone, you have to use the [setTimezone()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) method after the object is created.

Comment: Yeah Thanks! Got it to work for my test code. Now I have to check what is the problem with owncloud.  Thank you very mutch

Comment: If you want to thank me, upvote and accept my answer. :)

Comment: Creating DateTime object from timestamp = another wtf moment in php.

Answer (score 3):

Timezone is ignored when creating with microtime because in the vast majority of cases unix timestamps and microtime are stored as UTC. Use setTimezone after createFromFormat to update the timezone:

```
$micro = microtime(true);
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $micro);
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
```